# Web Directory is visible after React app deployed on cPanel

Tags: reactjs, cpanel, bundling-and-minification

I have created a simple react app and built the app using `npm run build` command and uploaded it to host. it works but whole application directory is visible in web browser console. So how do i fix it to not to show web directory on web console. Once the application kept growing and sensible data will visible. So is there any method to avoid that.

Here's the on cPanel File Manager

[image: cPanel File Manager]

and js directory has minified js like this,

[image: js directory content]

But once it loads on web browser it shows `App.js` content,

[image]

Any suggestions.

Comment: So after running "npm run build" , publish your "build" folder. Not your "public" folder.

Comment: of course i did publish build folder, but application directory shown like that.

Comment: You must have published more than you thought at some point. I'd say delete everything on your server and republish again. Your whole node_modules folder is right there in your files published. Your static folder, unbundled js files. None of it should be there. None of that ends up in the build folder. Other files have been published

Comment: okay i will try.

Comment: no use, same output.check this here, http://kuppiya.cc/react_test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running "npm run build" , publish your "build" folder. Not your "public" folder.

Comment: so how do i do it ?

Comment: Do what? You can't hide it. The build process is what you're already doing. Npm run build